# User Control is is not rendering in pagelayout in MOSS2007

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout, user-controls

Hi I registerd user control in pagelayout and trying use that but it seem like it not rendering any thoughts

```
%@ Register TagPrefix="sd" TagName="adbanner" Src="~/wpresources/usercontrols/AdBanner.ascx"%>
```

and i am using as

```
<sd:adbanner ID="adbanner" runnat="server" />
```

when i see in developer tools the above is displaying same its not rendring with actual user control

Answer (score 2):

Is the `runnat`attribute in your question a typo? If not then that could be the cause it should be `runat`

Comment: @Per nice catch :D

Answer (score 1):

- Put the user control into a subdirectory of `{SharePointRoot}/Templates/ControlTemplates`
- Register the control element at the top of page layout with **Full Assembly name**
- You need to add configuration to the `web.config` file so that your pages are allowed to use the user controls. You have to enable it within the web.config

Comment: thanks Falak but there are controls which are rendering but except  this one, i created new user control and trying to use

Comment: check my updated reponse!